# "Unable to find table" error when calling QSqlTableModel setTable method

Tags: c++, qt, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

I need to populate a QTableView by retrieving data from a QSqlTableModel object. I use following commands to make a connection to a sql server database:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg("localhost").arg("mydb");
db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);
```

I validate the database connection by the methods isValid() and open() from QSqlDatabase class. I am also able to query from the database tables properly. ٍEvery thing is ok so far. But the problem arises when I use following commands:

```
QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel(parent,db);
model->setTable("mytable");
qDebug() << model->lastError().text(); // the error message is printed on consul.
```

The method setTable not working and causes an error: Unable to find table \"mytable\".

Comment: is there a table named precisely 'mytable' in your 'mydb' database ? If so, can you query successfully it from another SQL client?

Comment: @Edd, yes I have it. I can read query it by QSQLQuery without any problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I should open the database right after setDatabaseName and before creation of QSqlTableModel:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg("localhost").arg("mydb");
db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);
db.open(); // :)
QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel(parent,db);
model->setTable("mytable");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#QSqlTableModel
the constructor of QSqlTablemodel:

> Creates an empty QSqlTableModel and sets the parent to parent and the
>   database connection to db. If db is not valid, the default database
>   connection will be used.

In the event that your db object is not valid you would connect to a default database where your table is not available.

Double check the parameters used to initialize and setup QSqlDatabase db.

Comment: As I said the database connection is ok since isValid() and open() methods of my QSQLDatabase object return true. I can query database by QSQLQuery.

Comment: Mh, if you say that the **same** db object works fine with QSQLQuery then I am not too sure. Maybe try updating your answer with the CREATE statement used to create the table, so people may have some extra info to tackle this

Answer (score -1):

In my case helped this:
So it's not about anything in QT, but it's in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. You need to be connected, then go to the folder 'Security', then to 'Logins', then right click on the user you use to login and go to properties, then change the default database to the database you want to use.

Problem was in this: QT used only default database, that was selected in SSMS and ignored specified database name.

Got solution from [QT tableview QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770355/qt-tableview-qodbcresultexec-unable-to-execute-statement)