# QT tableview QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement:

Tags: sql-server, qt, ssms

I'm trying to make a tableview that is connected to my ssms database / mssql database.
It opens the database perfectly, but it won't open the table.

This is the code:

```
void MainWindow::connectToDB()
{
    QString connectString = QStringLiteral ("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER<MYSERVER>;UID=<MYUSERNAME>;PWD=<MYPASSWORD>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"); 
    db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"DB OPENED";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"DB NOT OPENED";
    }
    tableView();
}



void MainWindow::tableView()
{
    QSqlQueryModel * model=new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM tblmeetgegevens");
    qry.exec();
    model->setQuery(qry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

The QT Debbuger gives me this information:

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'tblmeetgegevens'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared."

Comment: Does the table `tblmeetgegevens` exist in the **Default** database for the Login used to connect to the server? Also, why are you passing a username and password **and** using a trusted connection? If you're using a Trusted Connection the credentials of the user running the application will be used. Seems like, however, the problem is the lack of the database being specified and at a guess `master` is being queried; where you user object should must certainly not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not about anything in QT, but it's in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
You need to be connected, then go to the folder 'Security', then to 'Logins', then right click on the user you use to login and go to properties, then change the default database to the database you want to use.